# Preprocessing of sbt-twirl templates

Tags: scala, sbt, twirl

I need to preprocess some Twirl templates in my sbt project. Is it possible to define a task in build.sbt that will run *before* Twirl plugin compiles its templates?

Comment: If I define my custom source generator it is executed in parallel with Twirl generator, not before or after. I haven't found a way to make one source generator dependent on another one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sbt-web` allows the sequencing of the asset pipeline through `pipelineStages`:

```
pipelineStages := Seq(myPreProcessorTask, myTwirlTask)
```

Documentation:  [Writing an Asset Pipeline task](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-web#writing-an-asset-pipeline-task)

Source on [GitHub](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-web/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/web/SbtWeb.scala#L223).

Comment: Interestring. I'll try to use the same idea.